# C++ msgpack User-defined classes - can't get started

Tags: c++, macros, msgpack

I've been looking at the C++ quick-start guide for msgpack.

http://wiki.msgpack.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1081387

There, there is the following code snippet:

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class myclass {
private:
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
public:
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(str1,str2);
};

int main(void) {
        std::vector<myclass> vec;
        // add some elements into vec...
        /////
        /* But what goes here??? */
        /////

        // you can serialize myclass directly
        msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
        msgpack::pack(sbuf, vec);

        msgpack::unpacked msg;
        msgpack::unpack(&msg, sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());

        msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

        // you can convert object to myclass directly
        std::vector<myclass> rvec;
        obj.convert(&rvec);
}
```

I want to serialize a vector of myclass objects.

I've tried the following:

```
...
vector<myclass> rb;
myclass mc;

...

int main(){
    ...
    mc("hello","world");
    rb.push_back(mc)
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work ("error: no match for call")

also, if I do:

```
mc.str1="hello"
mc.str2="world"
```

it won't work as str1 and str2 are private.

How to use this MSGPACK_DEFINE(...) macro properly? I can't seem to find anything online.

Many thanks,

Comment: http://msgpack.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.5.4-1/msgpack__test_8cpp-source.html may help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MSGPACK_DEFINE(`) defines some methods implementing packing and unpacking for your class. What you put inside `()` is a list of the members you want serialized.

After that, you can pack and unpack your class just like you would pack or unpack an `int`. So the example should be working.

You can try removing the vector and pack only a single object - I think that would simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

```
class myclass {
    private:
        std::string str1;
        std::string str2;
    public:
        myclass(){};
        myclass(string s1,string s2):str1(s1),str2(s2){};
        MSGPACK_DEFINE(str1,str2);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<myclass> vec;
    myclass m1("m1","m2");
    vec.push_back(m1);

    // you can serialize myclass directly
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, vec);

    msgpack::unpacked msg;
    msgpack::unpack(&msg, sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());

    msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

    // you can convert object to myclass directly
    std::vector<myclass> rvec;
    obj.convert(&rvec);
}
```

Comment: I *think* this is out of date for the latest msgpack 4.x