# MessagePack C++ and Library Classes

Tags: c++, serialization, shared-libraries, msgpack

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326862/c-msgpack-user-defined-classes-cant-get-started?rq=1), it seems pretty clear that you can serialize your own structures. I need to serialize structures from an external (c language) library. How do you use msgpack with structs/classes that you cannot alter?

Kinda like this, just a concept of what I want to do:

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <msgpack.hpp>

FooObj* fo, fo2;
fo->bar    = 0x00ff0000;
fo->lounge = 0x0000ff00;
fo->saloon = 0x000000ff;

msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
msgpack::pack(sbuf, *fo);

//send as msg / recv as req

msgpack::unpacked unpacked;
msgpack::unpack(&unpacked, reinterpret_cast<char*>(req.data()), req.size());
msgpack::object obj = unpacked.get();

// convert it back into Foo
obj.convert(*bp);
```

To be more clear, the error I need to avoid is `/usr/include/msgpack/object.hpp:218:4: error: no member named 'msgpack_pack' in 'Foo'` from the linker.

*Note: If it is not possible to use msgpack in c++ with third-party -- not standard library -- classes and structs, I need to find a serialization solution that can handle that. And, if one has to write comprehensive wrappers for every third-party class to be serialized, I consider that not possible. A library that makes me need to synchronize code with **other** upstream changes just use it is not helpful to me.*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, but I've just had to deal with the same issue, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082028/2606891).